# State not updating in different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a searchbar component that I used context to import into another component. The state of the searchbar in its own component works but when I use the context to import it to another component it does not work. I have used other contexts in my project and they have worked but the searchbar state doesn't. I have no idea where to start, or how to go about fixing it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
export const SearchInput = () => {
const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type='text'
                    className='search-input'
                    name='search-movies'
                    value={searchInput}
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

//Use Context Component

export const SearchContext = React.createContext()

export function SearchProvider({ children }) {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    

    const value = {
        searchInput
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <SearchContext.Provider value={value}>
                {children}
            </SearchContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}

const Movies = () => {

    const { data, loading, isErr } = useFetch([
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/7077601?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/7078334?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`,
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/7078244?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`
    ]);

    const { watchList, handleClick } = useContext(WatchListContext);
    const { searchInput } = useContext(SearchContext)

    const [moviePoster, setmoviePoster] = useState(`giphy (1).gif`);
    const [movieTitle, setmovieTitle] = useState('');
    const [movieDescription, setmovieDescription] = useState('')

    const styles = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${moviePoster})`
    };


    SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

    return (

        <div className='movie-container'>
            {isErr && <div className="error">{isErr}</div>}
            {loading && <Spinner animation="border" variant="secondary" className="spinner" >
                <span>Loading...</span>
            </Spinner>}
            <div className='movie-hero' style={styles}></div>
            <div className="contains-descriptions">
                <h2 className="hero-movie-title show-movie">{movieTitle}</h2>
                <p className="hero-movie-description show-movie">{movieDescription}</p>
            </div>

            <section className="movies">
                <h2 style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '20px' }}>Action </h2>
                {data && <Swiper
                    spaceBetween={10}
                    slidesPerView={6}
                    pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                    scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
                    onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
                    onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
                >
                    {data && data[0].items.map(movie =>
                        <SwiperSlide key={movie.id}>
                            <div className='movie' >
                                <img onMouseOver={() => {
                                    setmoviePoster(`${"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original" + movie.poster_path}`);
                                    setmovieTitle(movie.original_title);
                                    setmovieDescription(movie.overview);
                                }}
                                    src={'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + movie.poster_path} width='250' height='300'
                                    alt='Promotional Poster For Movie'
                                />
                                <button className="watchlist-btn"
                                    onClick={() => handleClick(movie.original_title)}>
                                    {watchList.includes(movie.original_title) ?
                                        <i className="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> :
                                        <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    )
                    }
                </Swiper>}
            </section>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of a component that uses the context? To use the context a component must A) import `SearchContext` and declare for example `const context = React.useContext(SearchContext)`, and B) actually be contained within the `children` of `SearchProvider`.

Comment: @lawrence-witt, I've added the component that uses the another context as well as the SearchContext. I believe I have done them right because the functionality works. I think something is wrong with the way the search input is re-rendering or something

Comment: Your component looks fine. I guess the only thing that stands out is that `SearchProvider` does not provide `setSearchInput` so there's no way for that state to be updated. If you're expecting the `SearchInput` component to do that, it won't, unless it uses the setter from the context.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I thought the state was already set in the SearchInput Component. I would have to set the state again? And if I do, how do I use the setter from the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming a component tree that looks something like this:

```
+-- SearchProvider
|   +-- SearchInput
|   +-- Movies
```

Your `SearchProvider` should be providing both the state and the state setter as its value:

```
export const SearchContext = React.createContext()

export function SearchProvider({ children }) {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    
    const value = {
        searchInput,
        setSearchInput
    };

    return ...
}
```

Your `SearchInput` should no longer be controlling its own local state. That state now has to be shared with the rest of the tree. Instead, it subscribes to the context and updates it directly:

```
export const SearchInput = () => {
    const { searchInput, setSearchInput } = React.useContext(SearchContext);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    };

    return ...
}
```

Comment: So, I understand this part. What do I need to return from them though. Do I return the input for them both?

Comment: The returns can stay exactly the same as your original example.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using context and not just useState and props?

I think it would work with something like the following:

```
export const SearchInput = (props) => {

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type='text'
                    className='search-input'
                    name='search-movies'
                    value={props.value}
                    onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}


export function SearchCompoent({ children }) {
    const [searchInputValue, setSearchInputValue] = useState('');
    return (
        <SearchInput value={searchInputValue}>
            {children}
        </SearchInput>
    )
}
```